# How can I set custom error message and prevent redirect while submitting form in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, date-range, laravel-7

This is the form. I need to prevent this form from submitting along with a message(message similar to invalid entry in form) if the date range is greater than 1 year. Or maybe can we just not allow user to enter date range greater than 1 year in return.

```
<form role="form" action="#" method="POST">
    @csrf
    <div class="col-sm-1">
        <label for="startdate" class="form-control">From:</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <input type="date" name="startdate" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
        <label for="enddate" class="form-control">To:</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <input type="date" name="enddate" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
        <button type="submit" class="form-control btn btn-primary">Filter</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

The date range must be at most one year.

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript to validate if the date difference is more than a year. Once that is done, let it to your controller. For that put an alert that the date difference should not be more than a year

Secondly, in input forms with `type = "date"` there is a field option called `max` which can be used to show max date in a calendar `<input type="date" max="2021-07-08"/>`. Use that to set `enddate` when a `startdate is input`

Thirdly, put a logic to validate the date difference inside the controller as well for security

```
<script>
function callstart() {
    startdate = document.getElementById("startdate").value
    currentDate = new Date(startdate)
    var newDate = new Date();
    newDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate()+365);

    var year = newDate.getFullYear()
    var month = ("0" + (newDate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2)
    var date = ("0" + newDate.getDate()).slice(-2)
   
   // Write min date after a year in end date input form
    document.getElementById("enddate").max = year + "-" + month + "-"+ date
    
}

function callend(){

    var enddate = document.getElementById("enddate").value

    // validate if the date difference is more than a year

    const diffTime = Math.abs(new Date(enddate) - new Date(startdate));
    const diffDays = Math.ceil(diffTime / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)); 
    if(diffDays > 365){
        alert("date difference should not be greater than a year")
    }
}

</script>

<form role="form" action="{{ route('admin.report') }}" method="POST">
    @csrf
    <div class="col-sm-1">
        <label for="startdate" class="form-control">From:</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <input type="date" name="startdate" class="form-control" placeholder="Date"  onchange="callstart()" id="startdate">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
        <label for="enddate" class="form-control">To:</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <input type="date" name="enddate" placeholder="Date"  onchange="callend()" id="enddate" max="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
        <button type="submit" class="form-control btn btn-primary">Filter</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: The `if` condition appears to be the opposite of what had been asked for ...read slowly.